# Magento - opcheckout.js - manually calling setAddress() during checkout

Tags: javascript, magento

I've added PO Box filtering per this short tutorial:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/prevent-po-boxes-in-shipping-address-field-on-checkout/comment-page-1/#comment-35117

Essentially, this simply calls my controller, does a preg_match on the 'street1' and street2' fields, and gives an alert if a PO Box address is entered, else it just calls shipping.save() and goes to the next step.

The problem is that if a user has a PO Box address saved (and this is not the default address), when you select the alternate address (with the PO Box), the hidden form fields aren't updated with the selected address, and the PO Box validation does not get called.

In an attempt to remedy this, I am firing shipping.setAddress(value) when the select element is changed:

```
jQuery("#shipping-address-select").change(function(){
    var value = jQuery("#shipping-address-select option:selected").val();
    shipping.setAddress(value);
});
```

This works almost entirely as expected, it sets the address to what I expect, and everything is nice and wonderful; however, a small glitch that occurs here is that after calling shipping.setAddress(value) (which performs an ajax call), the select element automatically will display the 'New Address' option after I've chosen an actual address. This is purely a visual glitch, as the correct address is used, but having it show 'New Address' will be confusing to users.

Is there a way to remedy this without resorting to modifying anything in opcheckout.js (where the Shipping class and setAddress() bits reside)?

-- edit --
This is Magento Professional - 1.11.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While certainly not an optimal solution, in the meantime I have had to resort to updating the hidden form fields manually using:

```
jQuery("#shipping-address-select").on('change',function(){
    var address = jQuery("#shipping-address-select option:selected").html().split(', ');
    jQuery("#shipping\\:street1").val(address[1]);
    jQuery("#shipping\\:street2").val(address[2]);
});
```

I am so proud of this code. /sarcasm.